# Print values by certain indexes from an array

Tags: java

I have an array:

```java
int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

I need to print some values by index from 1 to 5, why I can not do so in java like this?

```java
System.out.println(arr[1, 5])
```

How it should be done then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a new array. You could do so with `copyOfRange` (as you can specify the start and end indexes) like so:

```
int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, 5);
```

Then, to print the array, you can use `.toString()` like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
```